# Counting sub-directories from a log file containing directory paths in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a huge log file which contains directory paths as one of the columns. For instance,

```
/
/a 
/a/b
/a/b/e
/d
/d/f
/e
```

There are no duplicate lines in the log.

My question is, using Pig, how do I count the number of sub-directories under each directory without counting the same directory name more than once? 
In the example above, the desired result would be somewhat like the following,

```
/ 6
/a 2
/a/b 1
/a/b/e 0
/d 1
/d/f 0
/e 0
```

My approach was to first split each of these paths and assign to it the corresponding directory depth value. For instance, /a/b will be changed to 3 new records,

```
/ 2
/a 1 
/a/b 0
```

Then I tried to group similar paths and sum the depth values present in each tuple. However, these results are inaccurate as they don't consider the fact that for each record, a path which is split will be counted more than once. 
How can I achieve the desired output? 
Any kind of help would be very useful. Thank you.